# передать пользователя во vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

как во vue.js передать пользователя, авторизованного на сайте, основной компонент Shop там у меня лежит шаблон и роут

есть страница магазин

```
<div id="app">
</div>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

файл app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import routes from './shopRoute'
import Shop from './components/layouts/Shop.vue'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faShoppingCart,faHome,faStore,faArrowRight,faArrowLeft,faTimes,faUserTie,faPencilAlt,faTrashAlt,faSearch } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

library.add(faShoppingCart,faHome,faStore,faArrowRight,faArrowLeft,faTimes,faUserTie,faPencilAlt,faTrashAlt,faSearch)

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: 'history'
})


new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: router,
    components: { Shop },
```

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под "передать пользователя"?

Comment: например передать Auth::user() (имя, почта, логин, аватар)

Comment: Вам нужен Vuex - это хранилище состояния в Vue которое позволяет получать и записывать данные доступные из любого компонента Vue.

Либо же хранить пользователя в LocalStorage и получать доступ к нему из каждого необходимого компонента.